# AIR create local SQLite db from downloaded schema file

Tags: mysql, sqlite, air

I'm developing an AIR app which will synchronise data between local SQLite db and server-side MySQL database.

The app is to be used by several users on any number of desktop computers. When a user first installs the AIR app the database and its tables will not exist locally. I would like the app to be able to download a single schema file with all the CREATE TABLE statements and execute them to set up the database tables locally prior to synchronising with server-side data.

I know that flash.data exposes the SQLSchema class which allows inspection of the database schema - but what I would like to do is build a local database from a downloaded schema.

Is this possible?

Thanks in advance.

Best wishes

Answer (score 0):

This is possible.

My way of doing this is through URLRequest which brings back the sql text file with commands to populate tables in main database opened by AIR.